# Screen always hangs when I try recording my screen with kazam

Tags: sound, video, 16.04

I have been trying to do some video recording using `kazam` screen recorder but my laptop screen always hangs and play and keep doing the same thing. At the end the video will be playing but the sound will not be very clear.

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can some one help me out?

Comment: So, the recording works, but when you play it back, the screen appears to have hanged in the recording? or is it recording at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple Sceen recorder. Works fine with 16.04 LTS.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```